# Checkout from TFS with MSBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild

What's the easiest way to checkout a file from our TFS with MSBUILD.

From what I can see it's to shell out to TF.EXE and manually call the checkout command. Is there really no built in command?!

Comment: what's wrong with shelling out to TF.exe?

Comment: nothing. but i was hoping for greater integration between msbuild and tfs when i asked this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There really is no built in command. Even worse, the tf checkout command only accepts a single filespec.

The recently released [MSBuildExtensionPack](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack) has some msbuild commands for TFS, but no perf gain there. Under the hood, they shell out to tf.exe

Answer (score 5):

the 'itemspec' can be a list of space-delimited items and can use wildcards.